# Updating state is breaking ads and image shuffle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

So I have been coding this simple clicker game which has ads and a card match minigame. On the iPhone simulator the ads and card match work as they should however once on a mobile device they start to break. Every single time the auto earnings update it changes the ad and when in the card match minigame, reshuffles the cards. The same thing happens when the screen is tapped for manual earnings. I have narrowed the problem down to the function that auto ads to the earnings and the text that displays the current worth. Does anyone know how I can keep updating this value without causing the ads to reload and the card to shuffle. And also explain why this problem only occurs on physical devices and not the simulator.

Secondly Earnings Function:

```
func secondlyValue() {
    clicks += perSecondEarnings * Float(upgrades["MasterUpgrade"]!) / 10
    totalEver += perSecondEarnings * Float(upgrades["MasterUpgrade"]!) / 10

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
        secondlyValue()
    }
}
```

Earnings Text:

```
Text("\(format(floatNumber: Float(clicks))) Clicks").foregroundColor(Color("Licorice"))
```

Card Shuffle:

```
init(difficulty: Binding<String>,
    showGame: Binding<Bool>,
    anyGameOpen: Binding<Bool>,
    clicks: Binding<Float>,
    totalEver: Binding<Float>) {

    self._difficulty = difficulty
    self._showGame = showGame
    self._anyGameOpen = anyGameOpen
    self._clicks = clicks
    self._totalEver = totalEver

    self.images = [
    ("DiamondKitty", .cyan, .black),
    ("DiamondKitty", .cyan, .black),
    ("Kitty", .lightGray, .black),
    ("Kitty", .lightGray, .black),
    ("GoldenKitty", .yellow, .black),
    ("GoldenKitty", .yellow, .black),
    ("WizardKitty", .blue, .black),
    ("WizardKitty", .blue, .black),
    ("BlingKitty", .green, .black),
    ("BlingKitty", .green, .black),
    ("PartyKitty", .orange, .black),
    ("PartyKitty", .orange, .black),
    ("MexicanKitty", .brown, .black),
    ("MexicanKitty", .brown, .black),
    ("SneakyKitty", .red, .black),
    ("SneakyKitty", .red, .black),
    ("SmartKitty", .systemMint, .black),
    ("SmartKitty", .systemMint, .black),
    ("AngstyTeenKitty", .magenta, .black),
    ("AngstyTeenKitty", .magenta, .black)
    ].shuffled()

    self.shuffled = [
    [images[0], images[1], images[2], images[3]],
    [images[4], images[5], images[6], images[7]],
    [images[8], images[9], images[10], images[11]],
    [images[12], images[13], images[14], images[15]],
    [images[16], images[17], images[18], images[19]]
    ]
}
```

Ad Struct:

```
struct GADBannerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @State private var banner: GADBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: GADAdSizeBanner)
    let adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 50))
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let bannerSize = adSize
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        banner.adSize = bannerSize
        banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-////////////////////"
        banner.rootViewController = viewController
        viewController.view.addSubview(banner)
        viewController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bannerSize.size)
        banner.load(GADRequest())
        return viewController
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context){
        let bannerSize = adSize
        banner.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bannerSize.size)
        banner.load(GADRequest())
    }
}
```

The game is on the appstore under the name 'Kitty Clicker' if you want to see what I mean by the crazy updating. Unfortunately, the bug is currently in the latest update.

Comment: There's not enough here to reproduce the issue. Ideally, you'd include a [mre], although I understand that'll be challenging with the ad dependency.